# Split dictionary depending on key lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data dictionary with eeg, gyroscope and other data. For processing, I want to extract eeg and gyroscope data in seperate dicts. Therefore I have two lists with the keys of eeg and gyroscope. I made it work with two dict comprehensions, but maybe there is a smoother solution to this.

```
eegKeys = ["FP3", "FP4"]
gyroKeys = ["X", "Y"]

# 'Foo' is ignored
data = {"FP3": 1, "FP4": 2, "X": 3, "Y": 4, "Foo": 5}

eegData = {x: data[x] for x in data if x in eegKeys}
gyroData = {x: data[x] for x in data if x in gyroKeys}

print(eegData, gyroData) # ({'FP4': 2, 'FP3': 1}, {'Y': 4, 'X': 3})
```

Comment: `for x in data if x in eegKeys` can just be `for x in eegKeys`. And maybe make a function to reduce duplication.

Comment: If you're code is working correctly you might want to try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AlexHall the OP's code is safer if you don't know beforehand what `data` will actually contain.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers not necessarily, if `data` is missing a key in `eegKeys` that might be a good reason to throw an exception.

Comment: @ppasler, what should be the result if one of the keys doesn't exist within `data` dict? let's say `{"FP4": 2, "X": 3, "Foo": 5}`

Comment: I know the structure of my raw data and all keys exist.

Comment: @JoséSánchez thanks I did not know this one, next time I will try it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Minor modifications, but this should be only a little bit cleaner:

```
eegKeys = ["FP3", "FP4"]
gyroKeys = ["X", "Y"]

# 'Foo' is ignored
data = {"FP3": 1, "FP4": 2, "X": 3, "Y": 4, "Foo": 5}

filterByKey = lambda keys: {x: data[x] for x in keys}
eegData = filterByKey(eegKeys)
gyroData = filterByKey(gyroKeys)

print(eegData, gyroData) # ({'FP4': 2, 'FP3': 1}, {'Y': 4, 'X': 3})
```

Or, if you prefer an one-liner:

```
eegKeys = ["FP3", "FP4"]
gyroKeys = ["X", "Y"]

# 'Foo' is ignored
data = {"FP3": 1, "FP4": 2, "X": 3, "Y": 4, "Foo": 5}

[eegData, gyroData] = map(lambda keys: {x: data[x] for x in keys}, [eegKeys, gyroKeys])

print(eegData, gyroData) # ({'FP4': 2, 'FP3': 1}, {'Y': 4, 'X': 3})
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks a lot cleaner to extract the dict comprehension, but as mentioned in comments I prefer a real method over a lambda expression.

Answer (score 10):

No, two dict comprehensions are pretty much it. You can use [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to select the keys that are present, perhaps:

```
eegData = {key: data[key] for key in data.keys() & eegKeys}
gyroData = {key: data[key] for key in data.keys() & gyroKeys}
```

Use `data.viewkeys()` if you are using Python 2 still.

Dictionary views give you a *set-like object*, on which you can then use set operations; `&` gives you the intersection.

Note that your approach, using `key in eegKeys` and `key in gyroKeys` could be sped up by inverting the loop (loop over the smaller list, not the bigger dictionary):

```
eegData = {key: data[key] for key in eegKeys if key in data}
gyroData = {key: data[key] for key in gyroKeys if key in data}
```

Comment: Thanks, inverting the loop is a great idea!

Answer (score 6):

If you are in Python 3, an updated inline solution could be:

```
second_dict = dict((d, first_dict.pop(d)) for d in split_keys)
```

`pop` would gently remove elements from the first dict and the generator with create the mapping to be passed to the dict constructor. Also you can use the good old dict comprehension.

Comment: I'd suggest `{d: first_dict.pop(d) for d in split_keys}` for readability, but it’s just a matter of taste really.